# Prevent addEventListener duplicate on elements

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on a project using `TypeScript` and I'm facing an issue on elements having duplicate `addEventListener` to it.

The way the application works is that when the page first loads, nothing gets executed. All the `TS` classes keep alive waiting for an event to be dispatched. This event comes from the backend that will tell the application that it's ready to start.

```
const dbEvent = new CustomEvent("backendLoadEvent");
document.dispatchEvent(dbEvent);
```

When the `TS` class receives this event, it starts itself going through the dom getting the elements and applying all the `eventListeners` necessary for it to work properly.

Inside the `TS` file I will add the listener just as usual:

```
const btnOrder = document.getElementById('btn-order');
btnOrder.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // Business logic here
  console.log('debug button order click');
});
```

The problem is that the backend gets fired multiple times which is causing the button clicked to be executed multiple times as well. For example, sometimes that `console.log` inside the event click gets triggered twice simultaneously.

I tried to do something like this:

```
const btnOrder = document.getElementById('btn-order');

if (btnOrder.getAttribute('listener') !== 'true') {
  btnOrder.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const elementClicked = e.target;
    elementClicked.setAttribute('listener', 'true');
  });
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it relies on the click, so if the user clicks after the second event from the database, it's not going to work. I don't know when the event will arrive at the application nor when the user will click on the button.

Is there another approach I could use to prevent this behavior?

> Note this is a simple example, but in some elements of the page there are a lot of events, this is a dashboard project. So we have like open/close modals, order and filter tables, add, remove and edit items on the table, and so on...

Comment: There is a chance instead of attaching event listeners to elements what you really need is event delegation.

Comment: @zerkms this would improve my code already because I don't need to manually declare multiple addEventListener. But how does it prevent the event from being added twice? Even if it's a parent element on the dom?

Comment: You add it just once on application load.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, but for example, if I have a table to be sorted by name, if the backend takes longer to give me the data, the button will be ready to be clicked before the data arrives and if the user clicks, its going to throw an error since there is no element to be sorted. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In a button handler you add as much logic as you need.

Comment: @zerkms Is there a way to achieve this with `addEventListener("change")`? For examplo, add the event listener on the `<section id="watch_this"><select><option>...</option></select></section>`

Comment: You add an event listener to the whole `<section id="watch_this">` or may be even the whole document, then in a handler check what element exactly was changed.